# Who was the kul guru of Hastinapura before Kripacharya?

Tags: mahabharata, kripa

Kripacharya, the immortal rishi is the kul guru of hastinapur but who was the kul guru of hastinapur before him?

Comment: If you know the answer then you can self answer too. But self answering mustn't be done frequently.

Comment: Also, from the way you write most of your questions, it gives the impression that you already know the answers and you want to test the knowledge of others. If you really don't know the answers then you have to make your questions look like genuine questions. May be tweak a little bit while framing the questions?

Comment: Okay but I really do not know who is the kul guru of hastinapur before kripacharya

Comment: Okay that's fine but do consider my other suggestion when writing your future questions.